# Каким образом можно реализовать сортировку массива словарей?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, словарь

Изучаю js. При написании приложения столкнулся с тем, что не понимаю того, как сортировать задачи. Сами задачи у меня выглядят в виде массива словарей:

```
[
{text: 'Новая задача', key: "boljqi", date: 1650299756531},
{text: 'Ещё новая задача', key: "eajs", date: 1650299743639}]
```

Каким образом можно вытаскивать отсюда дату, чтобы отсортировать массив по ней через array.sort()?

Хочу сделать что-то подобное, но пока не понимаю как:

```
const sortDownFunc = (list) => {
  setItemList((list) => {
  return list.sort((a, b) => b - a)
});    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь функция отсортирует список задач и вернет самые свежие

```
const sortTasksByDate = tasks => {
  return tasks.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date);
}

console.log(sortTasksByDate([
  { text: 'Новая задача', key: "boljqi", date: Date.now() },
  { text: 'Ещё новая задача', key: "eajs", date: Date.now() + 20 }
]));
```